# TimeStamp Difference Between Java and SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, time, unix-timestamp

Hello I have and SLQLite database in which I have table water_logs

```
CREATE TABLE water_logs( 
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
amount REAL NOT NULL,
icon INTEGER NOT NULL,
date INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

I store date in milliseconds.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

My problem is I want to get the day from the my date column using `strftime` function. The problem is tjat java calendar timestamp is different from SLQLite time stamp

```
1436859563832 --> result from cal.getTimeInMillis();

1436607407--> SELECT strftime('%s','now')
```

What I'm  actually trying to do is to group records by day. The following SQL query works just fine if value of SELECT strftime('%s','now') is paste in the date column

```
SELECT SUM(amount), date(`date`) FROM water_logs
GROUP BY date(`date`, 'unixepoch')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to me that you are using 2 different value types.

When you use

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

The output value is in **Milliseconds**, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()).

While when you use

```
strftime('%s','now')
```

The output value is in **Seconds**, as described [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

So, that might be the cause for the mismatch between the two values.
Of course that the value in seconds might undergo some rounding which might change its value a little.

Comment: Thanks man that was  it. I need to divide milliseconds to 1000 before store them in the database because in the DB value is stored as seconds.

Answer (score -1):

I will try to provide you the best way to store Dates in SQLite database.

1) Always use integers to store the dates.

2) Use this utility method to store the dates into the database,

```
public static Long saveDate(Date date) {
    if (date != null) {
        return date.getTime();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Like,

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_NAME, saveDate(entity.getDate()));
long id = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

3) Use this utility method to load date,

```
public static Date loadDate(Cursor cursor, int index) {
    if (cursor.isNull(index)) {
        return null;
    }
    return new Date(cursor.getLong(index));
}
```

like,

```
entity.setDate(loadDate(cursor, INDEX));
```

4) You can also order the data by date using simple ORDER clause,

```
public static final String QUERY = "SELECT table._id, table.dateCol FROM table ORDER BY table.dateCol DESC";

//...

    Cursor cursor = rawQuery(QUERY, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        // Process results
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot help me because the date stored mention in step 2 still write the date in different format in the DB which I do not want because I cannot convert it to java.util.Date

Comment: Man you misunderstood my problem I've edited the question and I add 3 screenshots to give you better idea